# Atlas Rocket Burning Hose

Tags: rockets, engine-design, identify-this-object

I was just watching The Right Stuff for the 100th time,and I've always wondered what is that hose spewing flame/burning propellant out of the bottom of the rocket. It's definitely not an engine,and why would the engineers have designed it that way. I have attached an image.[image: atlas carrying John Glenn into orbit]

Comment: It's already been answered. Knowledge is power. Thank you for responding. Since John and All of The Merc 7 were with us for many years after the program ended,it's nice to know that what appears to be thrust, is in fact a device to keep the rocket motor from blowing up.

Comment: Naturally I lost the link, but somewhere SpaceX has posted a very detailed discussion of the evolution of engine design.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you should ever come across that again, I'd love to see it.  But as Stephen J. Gould said about evolution (paraphrased) "It's not a ladder, it's a bush."

Comment: @OrganicMarble  found it     https://everydayastronaut.com/raptor-engine/

Comment: @CarlWitthoft many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the turbopump exhaust from the booster (jettisonable) engines.

[image]

From *Spacecraft and Boosters* by Gatland p. 222-224

> Exhaust stack discharges fuel-rich efflux outside reverse aerodynamic
>   flow at base of missile

In other words, the main purpose of the long duct is to get the fuel-rich turbopump exhaust away from the bottom of the vehicle to prevent it being trapped there by recirculation and potentially igniting.

The sustainer engine turbopump exhaust goes into its nozzle instead using an "aspirator", you can see that duct marked #41 on the schematic.

It looks like there were several variants of the design over the Atlas program.  There's lots of good information on this [page](http://www.b14643.de/Spacerockets/Specials/Atlas_MA-drive-system/index.htm) including this schematic

[image]

and this photograph.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That has driven me crazy ever since I first saw the movie,documentaries,or any video footage of the Atlas in operation. For the extreme novice such as me that only knows the basics of rocketry,you would expect the thrust to be coming only from the engine bells and nowhere else. It's a comfort to know,as history confirmed,that it was not a malfunction. :)

Comment: Done. I have one more question. Is this issue similar to what Apollo dealt with by designing the engine bells/thrust nozzles with Special Fins inside to keep the exhaust from producing vortices that could allow the engine to explode. Forgive me if my tech talk is seriously incorrect.

Comment: @RayG Thanks! I am not aware of any fins inside Apollo engine nozzles, but that could be a question on its own. If you find a picture or other reference showing what you mean, ask another question if you care to do so.

Comment: @RayG: The turbopump exhaust provides little or no thrust, it's a source of losses for this type of engine. More efficient engines run the turbopump exhaust through the main combustion chamber, which allows all the propellant to be used as reaction mass, but makes the engine more complex. The Falcon 9 has similar exhaust ports, though it doesn't bother with ducting it away from the rocket (the base of the booster can take a bit of heat from recirculating gases).

Comment: Thank you very much Christopher James Huff. What I find most amazing is how little the average joe,(including myself) knows about the technology that allowed us to reach our country's ( the USA) to reach the moon in 68. It tells me that it's time to hit the books.

Comment: @RayG and now you'll always notice the turbine exhaust for the fuel pumps in every rocket launch....

Comment: @RayG _engine bells/thrust nozzles with Special Fins inside to keep the exhaust from producing vortices that could allow the engine to explode_ Do you mean the [baffles on the injector plate](http://heroicrelics.org/info/f-1/f-1-injector/f-1-5u-injector-sm.jpg)?

Comment: @zovits Indeed. The followup question is here: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41331/6944

Comment: well, @Criggie, those that don't use closed cycle engines, and those that don't use the exhaust for film cooling.