# Saturn V and Atlas Engines exhaust issues

Tags: engine-design, saturn-v

[image: Views of the F-1 injector plate with baffles]

This is a follow up question to "Organic Marbles" [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41329/20636) to my earlier question about the [atlas rocket exhaust nozzle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41328/atlas-rocket-burning-hose), regarding the Apollo F1 thrust nozzles having metal baffles/fins inside to prevent the exhaust from spinning around inside the nozzle and exploding the engine/rocket.

My question is, were the nozzle exhaust pipes on the Atlas rocket engines, and the baffles installed inside of the F1 nozzles of the Saturn V first stage, dealing with the same issues of safely venting exhaust gases away from the rocket, or are they different issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The baffles on the F-1 and other engines such as early versions of the SSME (described [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38469/do-any-rocket-engines-besides-the-f1-need-require-baffles)) are intended to prevent the occurrence of high-frequency [combustion instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion_instability) in the engine's combustion chamber.  Uncontrolled combustion instability can destroy an engine due to

> excessive vibration force (which may break engine parts) or excessive
>   heat transfer (which may melt engine parts).

(from *Rocket Propulsion Elements*, Sutton, 4th edition, p. 257)

The Atlas turbopump discharge duct described in the linked question is dealing with a different problem, namely keeping flammable gas from accumulating under the rocket.

Two different problems with two different solutions.

Comment: Thank you again. It proves the point that the only stupid question,is the one not asked. Sorry about referring to you as organic matter. That's what I get for not reading thoroughly. Thank you Organic Marble. :)

Comment: "organic matter" in the injector plate had me baffled ;)

Comment: @aml Appropriate use of "baffled" as well!